# Is there any way to redirect through an esp8266 captive portal?

Tags: html, esp8266, arduino-ide

I am trying to create an html form in an esp8266 captive portal. I think the escape characters are messing it up.

I have tried everything I could find. I am using the backslash () to escape. I even tried using double quotes to escape ("). Nothing works.

```
/*Code above this*/
String responseHTML = ""
"<title>CaptivePortal</title>"
"<form action=\"website.com\" method=\"post\">"
"<label for=\"file\">Variable:</label>"
"<input type=\"text\" name=\"var\" />"
"<input type=\"submit\" />"
"</form>";
/*Code below this*/
```

I expect this to redirect you to website.com after filling out the form. This does not happen. The data does not get sent over. I have checked on website.com and everything is working there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the method to \"get\". The POST method does something different and will not generally load a web page (though its exact behavior will depend on the browser).

Your web browser almost certainly has a debugger or web console in it that you can use to see exactly what the browser is receiving and sending and what the results are. That can help you debug this kind of problem.

Comment: Your first paragraph is confusing - at least to me. From what I understand the captive portal page loads just fine. Hence, the system interacting with the ESP8266 correctly issues the GET request to which the device responds. POST is the standard method to submit form data to a resource; website.com in this example. However, we can't be sure if website.com is listening to GET or POST.